# How to report a faulty edit?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

The case goes like this: I get a notification that someone has edited an answer of mine. The edit doesn't make sense, so I roll back to the original answer. However, I don't know any place where I could comment on the edit, so that the person who made the edit knows why it got rolled back and can learn something.

Is this a missing feature or do I just not know about it?

Original edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9785094/revisions

Comment: The original edit is wrong, because you cannot add meta tags to the cache manifest, as it is not a html file.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to report it anywhere.

You can comment on your post using the name of the editor in a `@name` reply to address the editor if you feel the need to give feedback; editors can be addressed like that even if their name isn't auto-completed; just remove the spaces in the name; if their name is `First L`, then you can use `@firstl` in your comment and they'll get it in their inbox.

In this case, the last editor was a *reviewer* that 'improved' the change, but the change itself was suggested by an anonymous visitor. Because the reviewer made an additional edit you can still address him and point out the change was, in your opinion, incorrect.

Comment: I feel that maybe reporting and revoking some privileges (or just the warning message from the moderators) is needed for some users. IMO 2000 is not enough for many to enable free posts editing.