# How do we deal with faulty tag wiki edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I checked on a tag that I created a while ago, and I noticed an odd error in the tag description that I didn't remember making. When I inspected the history, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55172085/revisions

Using another edit, this user also incorrectly removed some punctuation from the tag wiki itself. This seemed a bit odd, and wanting to give them the benefit of the doubt, I took a look at their edit history, which revealed this pattern:

[image: Edit History]

They were clearly gaming the system to achieve the "Research Assistant" badge (they achieved the badge the very next day), but most of these edits negatively affected the tag wikis involved. Is there a better way to prevent this behaviour? They are a trusted user (20k+ rep), and so they can make tag wiki edits with practically no oversight.

I've read other posts on meta, such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366473/what-to-do-with-faulty-edits) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289103/how-to-report-a-faulty-edit), and the standard methods for dealing with faulty edits do not really apply to tag wikis.

- It is not possible to roll back or reject edits, even as the tag's creator.
- Tag wikis and excerpts do not have comments, so I cannot notify the editor directly.
- Likewise, tag wikis and excerpts are not posts, and so they cannot be flagged for moderator attention.

My only option seems to be to submit additional edits to elicit a rollback, and wait for them to get approved. This certainly works, but I can't help but feel that a better solution is possible.

One idea is to notify the most recent editor of a tag wiki if a new edit is approved, so that faulty edits could be undone more quickly. I don't think this would require too many changes to the existing infrastructure, and the hope is that this wouldn't result in too many notifications for users (tag wiki editors are rare).

Comment: Flag a post of that user for moderator attention and explain the problem. Mods will than deal with it.

Comment: It's very interesting how people become addicted to imaginary points and virtual badges, to the point of having all this trouble. This is an interesting subject for a thesis, I reckon.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You just described economy.

Comment: @TamásSengeland and finances ?

Comment: It truly is sad how pathetic some people can get on this site. I've had people mess with my posts by changing one character before. Whatever, not my problem some guy is hell bent on points.

Comment: Maybe we need some sort of "janitors" which themselves gain points for finding such bad behavior and flag it? So that we fight one "imaginary points addiction" with another? Then, after such a bad behavior is found, all its bad actions are deleted, points removed (maybe transferred to the user who found the bad behavior) and badge deleted (maybe permanently)?

Comment: @gog There should be some form of punishment. I flagged the user's latest post for moderator attention and explained the situation, so hopefully something will be done about it.

Comment: @JL2210 I agree with you, I was just thinking about how to auto-balance this. (In my thinking, you just acted like a "janitor", and once the bad behavior has been verified by a mod, you would gain points for finding such a bad behavior)

Comment: @gog I don't really care about reputation, just that this user stops doing this.

Comment: Eh fellas, remember to discuss about the user behavior rather than the user. Let us not get into a particular user's morality in the comments, please. I've deleted the comments. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten a response to my flag:

[image]